# Challenging vector modification

Tags: r, r-raster

I have what appears to be a simple problem but I can't figure out a way to fix it simply. I need to find a way to transform a numerical vector a way that it is increasing.  A example will be clearer...

```
vec1 <- c(3,3,2,3,1)
```

After passe into a function

> f(vec1)

should become

```
# [1]  1 1 2 1 3
```

The same way,

```
vec2 <- c(1,3,1,2,7)
```

should become

```
# [1] 1 2 1 3 4
```

and

```
vec3 <- c(2,1,0,0,4)
```

should become

```
 # [1] 1 2 3 3 4
```

Initially I've though that

```
as.numeric(as.factor(vec1))
```

would have worked but it's not working anymore (new version?)

For people that wonder why I need that, it's related to a bug in the raster package which I've presented here:
http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/bug-in-raster-stackApply-when-raster-not-in-memory-td7590584.html

but got no answer.  I then have to find a workaround.

I hope it's clear,
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a function with `match`

```
f1 <- function(x){
     match(x, unique(x))
}

f1(vec1)
#[1] 1 1 2 1 3
f1(vec2)
#[1] 1 2 1 3 4
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!  Perfect!  Thanks a lot for the quick answer!